# Select all images in image collection Google Earth Engine in R Rgee to mosaic

Tags: r, google-earth-engine

Is there a way to select all images in an image collection in Google Earth Engine or using Rgee?

I want to select all the images in an image collection after filtering the collection and then mosaic the images.

I know I can select individal images this way:

```
s2_sr16<-ee$ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')$filterBounds(SHP)$filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
listOfImages <- s2_sr16$toList(s2_sr16$size())
selected_images <- ee$ImageCollection$fromImages(list(ee$Image(listOfImages$get(1)), ee$Image(listOfImages$get(2)), 
                                                      ee$Image(listOfImages$get(3)), ee$Image(listOfImages$get(4)),
                                                      ee$Image(listOfImages$get(5)), ee$Image(listOfImages$get(6))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s2_sr16` and `selected_images` are *both* Earth Engine `ImageCollection`s. If you want all the images, then you can use `s2_sr16` that you already have.

I'm not familiar with R syntax, but by analogy with what you have so far, your desired mosaic would be written `s2_sr16$mosaic()`, to produce an Earth Engine `Image` from the collection.

---

Side note: the example code you started with is unnecessarily inefficient. You should avoid using `s2_sr16$toList(s2_sr16$size())` because it constructs a list as large as the entire collection, even though you are only ever using up to the 6th element of it. Instead, use `toList(6)` to use only the first 6 images from the collection. (But, in general, avoid using lists unless you need their precise functions — converting a large collection to a list is a good way to make your code run out of memory when you want it to work on larger problems.)